# Quiero ponerle texto a una imagen pero cuando escribo el texto no se muestra en la imagen

Tags: android, android-studio, canvas, edittext, bitmap

Estoy haciendo un mini editor de imagenes donde se le puede poner texto, pero cuando escribo en el EditText y lo transfiero a la otra actividad solo se muestra la imagen sin el texto AYUDA!!!!!

**Actividad del Editor**

```
public class Editfoto extends AppCompatActivity {

private static Bitmap bitmap_transfer;

public static Bitmap getBitmap_transfer() {
    return bitmap_transfer;
}

public static void setBitmap_transfer(Bitmap bitmap_transfer_param) {
    bitmap_transfer = bitmap_transfer_param;
}

EditText editText;
ImageView imageView1;
Button buttonok;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_editfoto);


    editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);


    imageView1 = findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            imageView1.buildDrawingCache();
            setBitmap_transfer(imageView1.getDrawingCache());


            Intent comenzar = new Intent(Editfoto.this, Touchedimage.class);
            startActivity(comenzar);


        }
    });

 
}}
```

**Layout del Editor**

```
xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context=".Editfoto">


    androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:drawingCacheQuality="high">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:background="@drawable/f"
        android:drawingCacheQuality="high" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:fontFamily="@font/impact"
        android:hint="Escribe texto aqui"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="40sp" />


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity donde paso la imagen**

```
 public class Touchedimage extends AppCompatActivity {

 ImageView imageView2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_touchedimage);

    imageView2 = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    imageView2.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),Editfoto.getBitmap_transfer()));



   }
 }`
```

**Layout de Del Activity donde paso la imagen**

```
 ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
 RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#000000"
 tools:context=".Touchedimage"
 android:orientation="horizontal">



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />



       </RelativeLayout>
```

> **IGNOREN ESTO** Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma de poner pasar información de un intent a otro, es pasándole la información directamente mediante el método `putExtra()`.

Por lo que veo, en la clase Touchedimage, has creado el componente de la imagen, pero no del texto.

Yo lo haría de esta manera:

1. En Editfoto al hacer click en el botón, le pasaría mediante putextra el texto en el que previamente hemos escrito algo.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editfoto);


        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);


        imageView1 = findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                imageView1.buildDrawingCache();
                setBitmap_transfer(imageView1.getDrawingCache());


                Intent comenzar = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Touchedimage.class);
                comenzar.putExtra("texto", editText.getText().toString());
                startActivity(comenzar);


            }
        });
```

2. En Touchedimage recogería la información del putExtra y lo mostaría en su respectivo TextView (hay que crearlo antes).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".Touchedimage">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mitexto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="145dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="443dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="#FFFF"
        android:textSize="50dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Y en la clase:

```
public class Touchedimage extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView2;
    TextView mitexto;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_touchedimage);

        imageView2 = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);


        mitexto = findViewById(R.id.mitexto);

        imageView2.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),MainActivity.getBitmap_transfer()));

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        mitexto.setText(bundle.getString("texto"));

    }
}
```

Te dejo unas capturas:

[image: captura1]

[image: captura2]

¡Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Mi pregunta es: si guardo esa imagen en mi sdcard se guardara el texto con la imagen?

Comment: @Osdward No, para guardar la imagen con otra necesitas create una bitmap y dibujar en ella las 2 images que quieres juntar, asi guardas la imagen donde esta dibujada las 2.

Comment: @OsAndNoTi me ayudarías a como hacerlo con ese código?